# How to get a clicked element in React?

Tags: reactjs

Coming from jQuery, getting a clicked element was a breeze, but I'm having some issues with it in React. Basically, I've got a list, and I want to get a clicked list item (or its index) and animate it.

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) 
  {
    super(props)
    this.list_element = React.createRef()
    this.state = 
    {
        items: [
        { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
        { text: "Learn React", done: false },
        { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
        { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
      ]
    }
  }
 get_index ()
 {
     console.log(this.list_element.current.children)
 }
  render() {
    return (

        <ol ref={this.list_element}>
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <li onClick={ () => this.get_index()}>
              <span>{item.text}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
        </ol>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uo1L03ng/

However, I don't know how to get the clicked element in React.
Should I use componentDidMount() instead and use the plain JavaScript to get the clicked element and future DOM manipulation?

What would be the best method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in parameters to the `onClick` handler when mapping over your `items` array. [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) also gives you access to the index of the element, hence, you can pass it to your `doSomething()` method.

> Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r04300ojnp) to try it live!

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.list_element = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      items: [
        { text: 'Learn JavaScript', done: false },
        { text: 'Learn React', done: false },
        { text: 'Play around in JSFiddle', done: true },
        { text: 'Build something awesome', done: true }
      ]
    }
  }

  doSomething(item, index) {
    console.log(item)
    console.log(index)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ol>
        {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={item.text} onClick={() => this.doSomething(item, index)}>
            <span>{item.text}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `item` as *parameter* in your `onClick` function. And you should have `key` prop for `<li>` tag, if not, you'll get `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` And use `e.currentTarget` to interact with DOM element.

```
get_index(e, item) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget); // <li>
  console.log(item);
}
render() {
  return (
    <ol>
      {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index} onClick={e => this.get_index(e, item)}>
          <span>{item.text}</span>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simply try this way!**

```js
export default function App() {
  const detectClickedElement = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="parent" onClick={detectClickedElement}>
        <div className="child">Child</div>
        Parent
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong since the OP was only interested in detecting the clicked element in a list of rendered elements